# Magento 2 - How I can setup product price per quantity

Tags: magento2, admin, layout, price, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have some simple and configurable products in Magento 2, before in the Magento 1 version we have tier prices to sell this products with different price per quantity. How I can do this on Magento 2 version?

```
Buy 48 for £1.45 each and save 42%
Buy 80 for £1.25 each and save 50%
Buy 120 for £1.20 each and save 52%
```

Thank you

Comment: You can follow up this link https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-setup-tier-price-in-magento-2.html

Comment: for simple products, but for configurable? if you check the Price and Advanced Pricing are disabled for Configurable Products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tier price is available only for simple products  , there is no way by default to customize them for configurable products. 
For my opinion use Shopping Cart Rules .

You can download and learn this samples https://www.demacmedia.com/25-shopping-cart-price-rules-in-magento-2/ to see how rules works .

Comment: perfect can you tell me how I can do this with Shopping Cart Rules?

Comment: updated my question

Comment: can you download all that 25 rules and put here only the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

You can set Tier price by edit product.

Following link will be useful for you.

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-setup-tier-price-in-magento-2.html

Comment: for simple products, but for configurable? if you check the Price and Advanced Pricing are disabled for Configurable Products

Comment: you can’t edit the advanced price settings for a configurable product once it’s saved. They can be specified only while creating a new configurable product:

Comment: I already have that configurable products and was imported, each configurable product have more than 80 associated so is really impossible to made this when the product is created